# angular - append and execute script inside ng-view before append the template content within it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ngroute, ng-view

Since script can't be loaded inside templates, due to Angular's jQLite wasn't written to achieve it, I decided to add jQuery library before Angular since it checks for jQuery existence, and voila!, it works. But, the fact that I'm here asking a question, means that there's a 'but', so, the script doesn't execute before content loads. Of course, I made a little trick with routes.

In module's config section, I made this:

```
$routeProvider
            .when("Business/:Context/:View?", {
                templateUrl: function (url) {
                    return "Contexts/" + url.Context + "/" + (url.View || url.Context) + ".html";
                }
            });
```

Then let's say we set the route to *"#/Business/Test"* he most locate a file called Test.html on *"/Contexts/Test"*, right eh!. Let's say Test.html content is this.

```
<script>
    (function(ng){     
        console.log(ng)
        ng.module('MyApp').controller('TestController', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $http, $mdDialog) {
            $scope.name = "TestController";
            $scope.params = $routeParams;
            $scope.name = "John";
        });
    })(angular)
</script>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    Hola {{ name }}
</div>
```

And finally the real question: why is this happening? It's like the  is executed after or I don't know, because, looking the console:

[image: Console]

Angular exists but the controller isn't added in time.
Am I doing wrong? It this behavior allowed? Can anyone lead me in this trip?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to include the controller script with the view? Don't understand why and what the logic behind it? You have the **template** and the **controller**  and the reason is to separate the view/DOM and the business logic behind it.

In angular, the [script](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) tag ***Load the content of a  element into $templateCache**, so that the template can be used by ngInclude, ngView, or directives* so it doesn't interpulated the same as a `<script>` tag would be normally loaded.

They also state that *The **type** of the  element **must be specified as text/ng-template**, and a cache name for the template must be assigned through the element's id, which can then be used as a directive's templateUrl.*

So you're just not using the script tag as intended by angular.

Why not including the controller in a js file and load it from the root HTML, or by using `requirejs` or a similar library.

Comment: Kind of??!! it just was an idea. I just wanted to create a simple way to load controller and view, even I thought to find a way to load the controller script inside the <ng-view> in $when.resolve, it is possible??. The answer to your last question is that I would have a lot of scripts included in the HTML root, because it has to much controllers, and I would like to load them when app needs them, not at the first time.

Comment: @PedroMora That's way I also wrote that you can use `requirejs` or other library - Check [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) it's exactly for your case, when you have lots of controllers and you (rightly) want to load the controller when you need it. It's working great in my app so I recommend you to give it a try

Comment: Read this [tutorial](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router) on how to integrate it with [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)